# Возникает ошибка «Lost connection to MySQL server during query» при попытке синхронизации модели в Workbench 8.0. Что делать?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

При попытке в Workbench 8.0 синхронизировать локальную модель с удаленной базой MySQL 8.0 возникает ошибка (ровно через 30 секунд):
[image]

Вот установленные таймауты в Workbench:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот установленные таймауты на сервере MySQL 8.0:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне решить данную проблему?